# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URLSessionDataTask'

Tags: ios, api, swift3, option-type

I am getting this error, and after researching I still have no idea how to solve it.

Maybe it is something about swift 3 because it appeared when I updated it.

The exact error is in: `guard let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in`

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
class func faceForPerson (_ person:String, size:CGSize, completion:@escaping (_ image:UIImage?, _ imageFound:Bool?)->()) throws {
    let escapedString = person.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)

    let pixelsForAPIRequest = Int(max(size.width, size.height)) * 2

    let url = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=\(escapedString!)&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=\(pixelsForAPIRequest)")
    var request = URLRequest(url:url! as URL);

    request.httpMethod = "GET";
    guard let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let wikiDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            if let query = wikiDict.object(forKey: "query") as? NSDictionary {
                if let pages = query.object(forKey: "pages") as? NSDictionary {
                    if let pageContent = pages.allValues.first as? NSDictionary {
                        if let thumbnail = pageContent.object(forKey: "thumbnail") as? NSDictionary {
                            if let thumbURL = thumbnail.object(forKey: "source") as? String {
                                let faceImage = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: thumbURL)!))

                                completion(faceImage, true)
                            }
                        }else{
                            completion(nil, false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)else{
        throw WikiFaceError.couldNotDownloadImage
    }

    task!.resume()

}
```

Comment: `completionHandler: {(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in` should be `completionHandler: { data, response, error in`

Comment: `var request = URLRequest(url:url! as URL);` makes no sense. use just `var request = URLRequest(url: url!)`

Comment: You can put multiple bindings in a single `if` statement to avoid that pyramid of dom.

Answer (score 0):

This `guard let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in` doesn't create optional data task (it wont be nil), so you don't need to check optional with `guard let`, just use `let`

Also makes no sense you tried to force it become `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)`?